# AxesSubplot has no attriute xticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello I have this code using Python which allows to de some plots :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
x1 = np.array(np.arange(9))
y1 = x1
ax1.plot(x1,y1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
x2 = np.array(np.arange(9))
y2 = x2
locs, labels = ax2.xticks()
ax2.plot(x2,y2)
```

And the problem is that this line `locs, labels = ax2.xticks()` does not work. I don't understand why because usually I used this : `locs, labels = plt.xticks()` and it works.

Do you have a solution with ax which works ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: `locs = ax2.get_xticks()` and `labels = ax2.get_xticklabels()`

Answer (score 2):

When you are using axes to make plots you have to use `ax2.set_xticks()` method to set the xticks.

And it returns a single list of xticks' location. So using

```
locs, labels = ax2.set_xticks(x2)  # I pass x2 as the ticks here.
```

will raise a `ValueError` unlike `plt.xticks()` which returns the locations and labels of the ticks.

You have to use

```
locs = ax2.set_xticks(x2)
```

Comment: use `set_xtickslabel`